# MySQL - Movie Database Query including Null Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

For reference I am working on the Sakila rental DVD database outlined here (#2): http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/SampleDatabases.html

I am trying to find the runtime of all Sci-Fi movies each actor has been in, including those who have not been in a Sci-Fi movie. I have the correct query for those who HAVE been in a Sci-Fi movie, but I'm having trouble expanding it to include all actors even if the runtime is NULL.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT act.first_name, act.last_name, SUM(fm.length)
FROM film fm
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON fa.film_id = fm.film_id
INNER JOIN actor act ON fa.actor_id = act.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film_category fc ON fm.film_id = fc.film_id
LEFT JOIN category cat ON fc.category_id = cat.category_id
WHERE cat.name = 'Sci-Fi'
GROUP BY act.first_name, act.last_name
ORDER BY act.last_name ASC
```

This gets me all 167 actors who are in at least 1 Sci-Fi movie. I think my WHERE clause is not allowing NULL rows, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: My mistake, fixed that in my query but not in the post. Edited the post.

Comment: Why do you have `film_category` and `category`? Even if this is clear to you, if someone else works on the code after you, it may be confusing. If you really do need them both, I'd rename the latter to `X_category`, where X is what this really represents.

Comment: I didn't create the database. I agree it's a bit confusing. film_category contains the film_id and category_id. category connects the category_id with the category name. So to get the film name and its category, you need all three tables.

Comment: Ah right, film_category is a many-to-many table. OK, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the where clause is working on the far right side of your left joins...if it is null it's going to be filtered out because null does not equal 'Sci-Fi'.  Want nulls?  Tell the where statement to include them

```
 WHERE (cat.name = 'Sci-Fi' or cat.name is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have "cat.name = 'Sci-Fi' be a part of your ON clause in the outer join.

Unless your criteria is filtering in on nulls, you should never put criteria involving an outer joined table in the WHERE clause, as it turns the outer join into an inner join. The criteria belongs in the ON clause.

```
SELECT act.first_name, act.last_name, SUM(fm.length)
  FROM film fm
 INNER JOIN film_actor fa
    ON fa.film_id = fm.film_id
 INNER JOIN actor act
    ON fa.actor_id = act.actor_id
  LEFT JOIN film_category fc
    ON fm.film_id = fc.film_id
  LEFT JOIN category cat
    ON fc.category_id = cat.category_id
   and cat.name = 'Sci-Fi'
 GROUP BY act.first_name, act.last_name
 ORDER BY act.last_name ASC
```